# Why isn't my nib interfacing with my code?

Tags: iphone, sdk, uibutton

Can someone help me figure out this weird issue?

None of my button actions are getting called.

http://drop.io/cpyexk7

Comment: Why don't you elaborate the question a bit more. Maybe you don't make the nib connections right?

Comment: Post the code where you make the connections and state/show the connections you made in IB. Nobody wants to DL your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some common problems with these symptoms:

- You didn't set the class of your NIB properly. Make sure it's an instance of your view controller subclass, not UIViewController.
- You didn't create the appropriate IBAction outlets or connect them. Double-check that all the connections are made properly.

Without in-question code or pictures, I can't be more specific.